# error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator defined which takes a right-hand operand of type '' (or there is no acceptable conversion) Error executing

Tags: c++

whydo i get the error C2679:

```
#include <iostream

using namespace std;



int main()

{


    cout << "Enter your name:" << flush;

    string name;
    cin >> name >> endl;


    cout << "You entered:" << name << endl; 


    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: i have included the following headers #include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <istream>

Comment: In short: Please create an example that replicates the error you get, and that we can copy-paste and try for ourselves (that's the [mcve]). Then copy-paste the full and complete compiler output into the question body itself. And of course, please learn how to edit your questions (there's a link right below the tags).

Comment: A hint about your problem though: Learn what the [`std::endl`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/endl) manipulator is for and what it does.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> #include <iostream
> ```

You're missing a `>` - i.e. that should be

```
#include <iostream>
```

---

Also, you should

```
#include <string>
```

---

And, `endl` is for output, not input.  So,

> ```
> cin >> name >> endl;
> ```

should be

```
cin >> name;
```